# Can someone see my web history?

Tags: wireless-networking, history

If my devices do not have any viruses / trojans and I am on a password-protected wifi network, can someone see my web history from another device? If it is true how does it work?

Comment: "Chronology"?  Of What? Huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, anyone who knows the password to a password-protected Wi-Fi network can observe (capture and decrypt) the web traffic of anyone else on that network. Even if you use HTTPS (SSL/TLS) to protect the content of your web page loads, they can still see the names of the sites you're going to. This is true of all three ways Wi-Fi networks have been password protected over the years: WEP, WPA-PSK, and WPA2-PSK. WPA-PSK and WPA2-PSK made it a little harder but still totally doable.

If the network uses individual accounts (usernames *and* passwords via WPA2 Enterprise), then others probably can't observe your web traffic wirelessly.

Also, Wi-Fi encryption just protects your traffic across the local Wi-Fi link. If someone were to plug in a computer between the Wi-Fi AP and the broadband modem, they could observe all your traffic there as well. Again, using HTTPS everywhere will keep them from seeing the content you're looking at, but they can still know what websites you're visiting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways users can view your history:

- Use man in the middle (MITM) attack to see what you are currently browsing
- By sending a link one can inject malicious scripts to the browser and capture screen shots, sessions.
- If wifi password is not secure it can be cracked, and then the data transmitted can be sniffed from the air
- Even if the wifi is secure, the wifi router you're using could be have vulnerabilities that could be exploited through the wire. This could expose information.

Getting the current browsing history is quite easy. The attacker can capture while you surf. But it is quite difficult to hack previous history and is not generally possible without injecting viruses.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to local WLAN "leaks", your *internet provider* will see *all* of the requests you make. The provider might even be legally obliged to record and store the data (and/or to provide a port for interception), and to hand it over to authorities by request.